# Dynamic Prolog clause-body generation

Tags: dynamic, prolog, metaprogramming, code-generation, clause

For an assignment I have to generate a prolog procedure body dynamically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.19%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/manipterm.html%27%29%29) for the swi prolog manual description of relevant predicates.

As an example consider the following

```
goal :- Z =.. [foo, 1], 
    Y =.. [bar,2], 
    X =.. [',', Z, Y], 
    R =.. [':-', r, X],  
    assert(Z), assert(Y), assert(X), assert(R).
```

PS: Another possibility is lower class, but sometimes can be a better choice: just print out what you need to construct to a file.

Comment: up to date link? https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=terms

Answer (score 0):

assert/1, asserta/1, retract/1, retractAll/1, abolish/1

Answer (score 0):

to add a predicate you need to use asserta/1 or assertz/1 (assert/1 is deprecated) [more](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.12%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/db.html%27%29%29)
if you have already declared some of the clauses of the predicate in the code you loaded you should define the predicate as dynamic using dynamic/1 [more](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.13%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/dynamic.html%27%29%29)

forming the clause depends on the form of the input.
if you have a list with the name of the predicate and the arguments you can use [=../2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28=..%29/2)
if you have the clause on a string you can use [term_to_atom/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_to_atom/2) (it works both ways)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate dynamic predicate with '`(`' and '`)`' enclosing body.

```
assert(test(X):- (X1 is X+1,  write(X1)))
```